# How do I edit an commit message in svn?

Tags: svn

How do I change the message of my last commit message in Subversion?
I have not yet pushed the commit to anyone.
And how could one change the commit message after one have pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN is centralized VCS, so you can't commit but not push. Here is no 'push' at all.

All committed messages goes to server and become visible to everyone.

But you can change log message for already committed revisions. Google for revision properties (svn:log), a do not remember exact command line syntax.

If you use TortoiseSVN - open log, select revision and in context menu here will be item 'Edit Log Message' or something like this.

But do not forget about pre-revprop-change hook which can prevent changing revision properties.